# Bounded Harmonic Functions on the Disk

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, uniform-continuity

Denote by $\mathbb{D}$ the open unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. 
Is it possible to find a *bounded* harmonic function $u : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is not uniformly continuous?

I tried using functions that oscillate near $\partial \mathbb{D}$ but was unable to get anything substantial.

Comment: But aren't bounded harmonic functions constant ?

Comment: Wouldn't you need $u$ to be harmonic in all $\mathbb{R}^2$ for this?

Comment: For one we can use the inclusion map to make it harmonic on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I am not quite sure whether all the bounded harmonic functions on open disk are constant.

Comment: @YadatiKiran: Bounded harmonic functions **in $\Bbb C$** are constant. $u(x, y) = x$ is harmonic and bounded in $\Bbb D$, but not constant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any bounded measurable function $f\in L^\infty(S^1)$, the Poisson integral $P[f]$ gives a bounded harmonic functions in $B_1$. This function is continuous (equivalently, uniformly continuous) if and only if $f$ itself is continuous.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel) you can find what the Poisson kernel is and how it's used to build harmonic functions in the ball.

Said otherwise, $f\mapsto P[f]$ is a linear isometry of $L^p(S^1)$ onto $h^p(B_1)$. We used the case $p=\infty$, where $h^\infty(B_1)$ stands for the the bounded harmonic functions in the ball. You can read more about it [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_13/HFT.pdf).

Comment: If $f$ is discontinuous on $S^1$, then $P[f]$ is discontinuous when viewed as a function on $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$. But $P[f]$ is still harmonic and continuous in $\mathbb{D}$? I'm confused as to how I can conclude from this that $P[f]$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: If $P[f]$ were uniformly continuous in $\mathbb D$, it would extend continuously to the closure, but it can't, because its extension is discontinuous on $S^1$

Comment: Yes you are right in saying that $P[f]$ is discontinuous in $\bar{\mathbb D}$ and continuous in $\mathbb D$. The point is that it cannot be *uniformly* continuous in $\mathbb D$, otherwise it would be in $\bar{\mathbb D}$ too.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about this property.

Comment: I should probably have written it better :)

Answer (score 2):

Start with
$$
           \phi(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z},\;\;\; z\in\mathbb{C},\; |z| < 1.
$$
This function is holomorphic with
\begin{align}
    \Re \phi(z) &= \Re\frac{1+z}{1-z}\frac{1-\overline{z}}{1-\overline{z}} \\
     &=\Re\frac{1+z-\overline{z}-|z|^2}{|1-z|^2} \\
     &= \frac{1-|z|^2}{|1-z|^2} > 0.
\end{align}
$\psi(z)=e^{-\phi(z)}$ is bounded and holomorphic in $|z| < 1$, but $\psi$ is not uniformly continuous in the open disk.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\log$ denote the principal value $\log.$ Then $\log(1+z)$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb D.$ Hence its imaginary part, $u(z)=\arg (1+z),$ is harmonic in $\mathbb D.$ We have $|u|<\pi/2$ in the disc, so $u$ is bounded there. For small $r>0,$ $-1+re^{i\pi/4}\in \mathbb D.$ For such $r,$

$$u(-1+re^{i\pi/4})- u(-1+r) = \pi/4-0 = \pi/4.$$

But $(-1+re^{i\pi/4})-(-1+r) \to 0$ as $r\to 0.$ This shows $u$ cannot be uniformly continuous in $\mathbb D.$

Comment: Are you considering the principal value $\log$ where $\theta\in\left(\dfrac{-\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$ ?

Comment: @YadatiKiran Yes, but that should be $(-\pi,\pi).$

Comment: If its $(-\pi,\pi)$ then how do you say $|u|<\pi/2$ in the disc? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @YadatiKiran Because $1+z$ is in the right half plane

Comment: Oh Yes ! I get it.